# Uncaught in promise error in Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge

I am getting below error in only Microsoft Edge browser and all other browsers works just fine.

[image]

By looking into the error I am not able to understand what might be the issue with only edge browser. Can some one please suggest me something like how to debug this and what might be the general reason for this kind of error? My application is using Angular 7.3.

Comment: Please put the error in plain text. Some people cannot open imgur (like me). And post the offending code.

Comment: Can you please inform us which exact version of the Edge browser you are using for making this test? It can be possible that there is some error from the promise that you did not catch and that's why you got this error. Try to add catch for your promise and try to handle that error that may help to fix the issue. also, try to check that all the necessary polyfills are added to your project. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to enable [polyfills](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#enabling-polyfills-with-cli-projects) in order to use functions that aren't supported by the browser (such as IE and EDGE)